# How can I safely push a DIV all the way to the bottom

Tags: css, html, height, footer

I have a footer tag which is 100% (full width of screen) that I want the graybox to always push to the bottom (it stretches to screen bottom)

I have tried

`html, body{height:100%}`

And then applying `display:block;height:100%`

However, my div, the footer, just expands ALL the way and creates a huge scroll. My development site demo is http://dev.al-yusra.org/

Comment: get rid of `height: 100%;` and also search for sticky footer on google

Comment: Have you tried not applying any height at all?>..

Comment: Did any of the answers help or do you have more info?

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
body {
   min-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is a footer. The main trick is to set the footer bottom to 0, position to absolute and height. See [here](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14441693/css-footer-at-bottom-of-page) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your footer:

```
footer {
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: and maybe you could also add a little padding at the bottom of your footer, like `padding-bottom: 10px`